# Gitlab: How to git pull without credentials?

Tags: gitlab

I have generated an `id_ed25519` key on my server and set it in Gitlab, when I try to connect with SSH, I get the welcome message, but when using `git pull`, it's still requiring credentials (username and password).

```
$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Welcome to GitLab, @john.doe!
$ git pull
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': john.doe
Password for 'https://john.doe@gitlab.com': 
Already up to date.
```

What's missing in my configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it would be because you are using https git remote url instead of ssh one.

Comment: That was it, thanks! So I replaced `url = https://gitlab.com/john.doe/myproject.git` by `url = git@gitlab.com:john.doe/myproject.git` in `.git/config` in paragraph `[remote "origin"]` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your configured remote, it should be the https one:

```
$ git remote -v
origin https://gitlab.com/john.doe/myproject.git (fetch)
origin https://gitlab.com/john.doe/myproject.git (push)
```

You'll want to change it to the SSH one:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:john.doe/myproject.git
```

This does what OP mentioned in the comment of the accepted answer, without having to manually edit the config file. Please upvote the accepted answer before mine :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The currently accepted answer is no answer at all.  Lame.

Comment: Thanks @Aquarelle! However, half an answer that arrives in time is better than a complete answer that comes much later. It's perfectly reasonable to me that OP chose the only answer at the time. :)